# Should I add each image on app/assets/images to the assets precompile?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm using rails 4.

Added a file on app/assets/images/myimage.png

I want to use in my app so:

```
<%= image_tag 'myimage.png' %>
```

Wow that's really easy and nice! But wait.. that gives me this error

```
Asset was not declared to be precompiled in production.
Add `Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w( myimage.png )`
     to `config/initializers/assets.rb` and restart your server
```

This mean **EACH** image on my application have to be included in that array? Ugh..

But wait, my assets.rb have this comment:

```
 # ...and all non-JS/CSS in app/assets folder are already added.
```

So, it's added or not?

Comment: Or maybe I've to restart the server after adding an asset?

Comment: Yes, I've to restart server, ugh!